# Creating new fields in serializer that access another model's attributes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My API call to `api/business-review/3abe3a1e-199c-4a4b-9d3b-e7cb522d6bed/` currently returns the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": "3abe3a1e-199c-4a4b-9d3b-e7cb522d6bed",
        "date_time": "2016-05-31T19:18:24Z",
        "review": "Another quality job, Anna has a no fuss approach to his job and clearly takes pride in what he does. Will continue to use again and again.",
        "rating": "4.0",
        "person": "c1cc5684-1be1-4120-9d81-05aec29f352a",
        "employee": "ecdc1f99-138c-4f9f-9e1f-b959d59209aa",
        "service": "1dfa408f-d5bc-4eb2-96ae-e07e7999a01a",
    }
]
```

Now I want to create three new fields:

- `person_name` - which grabs the first_name and last_name of the reviewer
- `employee_name` - which grabs the first_name and last_name of the employee
- `service_name` - which grabs the title of the service

I've tried the following so far but it doesn't create any new variables:

**serializers.py**

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Class to serialize Review objects
    """
    person_name = serializers.CharField(source='person.reviewer.first_name', read_only=True)
    employee_name = serializers.CharField(source='person.employer.first_name', read_only=True)
    service_name = serializers.CharField(source='service.title', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = 'id'
```

**models.py**

```
class Review(models.Model):
    """
    Review model
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, default=None, related_name='reviewer')
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, default=None, related_name='employee')
    review = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, default=None)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)

class Person(models.Model):
    """
    Person entity
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Service(models.Model):
    """
    Service model
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: How are `Service` and `Review` models related?

Comment: A person can leave a review of a service

Comment: Please update the models code about their relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want add data to the serialized representation of your object, its better to use [`SerializerMethodField()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for `person_name`, `service_name` and `employee_name` fields.

> This is a `read-only` field. It gets its value by calling a method on
>   the serializer class it is attached to. It can be used to add any sort
>   of data to the serialized representation of your object.

Also, since the `ForeignKey` fields `person`, `employee` and `service` allow null values, you will have to handle the case when they are actually null. Otherwise, `AttributeError` exception will be raised on the serializer.

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Class to serialize Review objects
    """
    person_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    employee_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    service_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['person', 'service', 'review', 'employee', 'person_name', 'service_name', 'employee_name', 'date_time']
        read_only_fields = 'id'

    def get_person_name(self, obj):
        try:
            person_name = obj.person.first_name + obj.person.last_name
        except AttributeError: # handle case if person is null
            return None
        else:
            return person_name

    def get_employee_name(self, obj):
        try:
            employee_name = obj.employee.first_name + obj.employee.last_name
        except AttributeError: # handle case if employee is null
            return None
        else:
            return employee_name

    def get_service_name(self, obj):
        try:
            service_name = obj.service.title
        except AttributeError: # handle case if service is null
            return None
        else:
            return service_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding the field name explicitly instead of using `__all__` which only picks up fields which are present in model and not  those defined in serializer  like this

`fields = ['person', 'service', 'review', 'employee', 'person_name', 'service_name', 'employee_name', 'date_time']`